# How could I apply i18n.js on angular template with Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, internationalization

This is my html template file.

I know to use i18n.js is to call `i18n.t()` js function inside script tag

But how could I apply the i18n on the html template file ? For the `arrivals` and `destination`

Thanks

```
<div class="panel panel-transparent" ng-controller="arrivals_ctrl">
  <div class="panel-title">
    <h3>{{arrivals}}</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-transparent" ng-repeat="destination in arrivals_lst">
    <div class="panel-title">
      <h5>{{destination}}</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```